# Recopying character array using pointers and trimming leading white space

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm learning C++ on my own and was working on this problem:

> Write a function named trimfrnt() that deletes all leading blanks from a string. Write the function using pointers with the return type void.

My attempt at the problem is below and I tried solving this problem 2 ways (you can see my two functions `trimfrnt1()` and `trimfrnt2()`.  `trimfrnt1()` works fine.  I kind of got this working by accident.  After I coded it, I wasn't sure why it exactly it worked.  My confusion is at the `for` loop.  I drew a diagram of the msg array below:

```
             |<--ptrMsg--------->|
  |<------for loop---->|
   0    1    2   3     4   5     6    7
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |  G |  R |  E |  A |  T | \0 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  G |  R |  E |  A |  T |    |    | \0 |                             
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

### Question 1

From my diagram above, I was actually expecting the text:  "GREATAT" because of the overlap.  How is it that the entire string got shifted and re-initialized because I only looped through 5 letters?

### Question 2

The question states to use pointers so I though `trimfrnt1` was cheating because I was indexing so I tried to do another method of `trimfrnt2`.  This function I'm stuck at the while Loop:

```
    // shift characters to beginning of char array
    while( *(ptrMsg + count) != '\0' )
    {        
        *ptrMsg = *(ptrMsg + count);
        ptrMsg++;
        count++;
    }
```

This part of the code is not working for me.  When I print out `*(ptrMsg + count)`, I get the right characters, but when I assign it to the contents of the *ptrMsg, I get garbled characters.  In this case, I was also expecting "GREATAT" because I didn't reintialize the remaining characters.  Is there a way to do this using a pointer method as I am trying to do?

Thank you!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void trimfrnt1(char msg[], int size)
{
    char *ptrMsg = msg;

    // Find beginning of text
    while(*ptrMsg == ' ')
        ptrMsg++;

    // Copy text to beginning of array
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
        msg[i] = *ptrMsg++;

    // Reset pointer to beginning of array
    ptrMsg = msg;

    // Print array
    cout << "new msg1: ";
    cout << "\"" << ptrMsg << "\"" << endl;    
    cout << endl;

    return;
}

void trimfrnt2(char msg[], int size)
{
    int count = 0;      // used to find leading non-white space
    char *ptrMsg = msg; // pointer to character array

    // find first place of non white space
    while( *(ptrMsg + count) == ' ')
        count++;

    cout << "count = " << count << endl;

    // shift characters to beginning of char array
    while( *(ptrMsg + count) != '\0' )
    {        
        *ptrMsg = *(ptrMsg + count);
        ptrMsg++;
        count++;
    }
    cout << "count = " << count << endl;

    // Reset pointer to beginning of array
    ptrMsg = msg;

    // Print array
    cout << "new msg2: ";
    cout << "\"" << ptrMsg << "\"" << endl;    
    cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
    char msg[] = "  GREAT";
    const int size = sizeof(msg)/sizeof(char);

    cout << "Orginal msg:\"" << msg << "\"" << endl;

    trimfrnt1(msg, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The part of the question "Write the function using pointers" probably means that the input string will be a pointer.

Comment: in `trimfrnt1` you are actually looping too far in your `for`-loop. It loops `size` times, but the position you are copying _from_ goes beyond the end of your array. This causes Undefined Behavior, in your case (debugger?) it seemed to work.

Comment: In function `trimfrnt1`, check the for loop where you copy the string data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trimfrnt1()` has undefined behaviour - you `for` loop causes `ptrMsg` to reach beyond the array and thus you're reading memory which doesn't belong to you and anything could happen. It seems that on your platform, such reads are OK, so the loop happily copies the "random" junk from memory - but before that, it copies the terminating `NUL` character, so you cannot get `"GREATAT"` as a result. You should change the `while` loop like this:

```
while(*ptrMsg == ' ')
{
  ptrMsg++;
  --size;
}
```

This will still give you just `"GREAT"`, because the terminating `NUL` is part of the `sizeof` result.

In `trimfrnt2()`, your loop is wrong as you're incrementing `count`, which you shouldn't be. That's why it's good to give really descriptive names to variables. If it was called after its semantics (e.g. `numberOfSpaces`), you wouldn't even consider writing the increment in the copying `while()` loop. If you remove that increment, `trimfrnt2()` should give you the `"GREATAT"` result you expect.

---

For inspiration, here is how I would implement this using pointers without arithmetic:

```
void trimfrnt3(char *msg, size_t size)
{
  const char *src = msg;
  while (*src == ' ')
    ++src;
  char *dst = msg;
  while (*src)
  {
    *dst = *src;
    ++src;
    ++dst;
  }
  cout << "new msg: \"" << msg << "\"\n";  //don't use endl unless you want to flush immediately
}
```

As you can see, this version doesn't even use the `size` parameter, which could thus be removed.

Comment: Very good points.  Thx for sample code- very elegant.  What does `while( *src)` mean?  Does this execute while its not a null pointer?

Comment: @user1527227 `*src` is of type `char`, so it's an integral expression. Integral expressions implicitly convert to `bool` such that `0` becomes `false` and all other values become `true`. So it's the same as saying `while (*src != 0)`, which in turn is the same as `while (*src != '\0')`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in `trimfrnt2` is

```
*ptrMsg = *(ptrMsg + count);
ptrMsg++;
count++;
```

It will advance `ptrMsg` both for source and destination. You should remove `count++`. After loop, you should put `\0` in the result.

```
while( *(ptrMsg + count) != '\0' )
{
    *ptrMsg = *(ptrMsg + count);
    ptrMsg++;
    //count++;
}
*ptrMsg = '\0';
```

---

It may help you

```
void trim_left(char *msg)
{
    char *src = msg;
    char *dst = msg;

    while (*src == ' ')
        src++;

    if (dst == src)
        return; // Don't need trim

    while (*src)
        *dst++ = *src++;

    *dst = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There's already a `\0` in the array.  What happens when you add another one?

Comment: The `\0` should be right after last character not at the end of array, otherwise you have that un-trimmed string beside the trimmed string -- Also, I've added a trim function which may you like it.

Comment: Very elegant--thank you!  what does `while (*src) ` mean?  In other word when is this true?

Comment: When `src` equals to `\0` (zero indicates the end of the string).

Answer (score -1):

About the garbage value, its because after 2nd while loop,you're assigning a ptrMsg(char pointer) with Msg(char).
it should be

```
*ptrMsg=msg // or ptrMsg=&msg
```

moreover, you're printing ptrMsg in cout,which prints the address,not the value.

About why GREAT & not GREATAT,thats because msg & ptrMsg have very different addresses,ie you are not rewriting msg with ptrMsg.while defining ptrMsg, you copied the content of msg to ptrMsg, & not assigned the address....

```
ptrMsg=&msg  // ptrMsg contains address of string msg
*ptrMsg=msg  // address pointed by ptrMsg has same content as msg,but both have different address altogether
```

Comment: Most importantly, your question requires you to do the changes to the original message itself.ie, in main itself, you gotta have msg ='                        GREAT' before trim function call, & after that, same msg should have 'GREAT' as its content.